# memorystream - stringstream, string, others?

Tags: c++, string, stl, stream, buffer

i am reading in a binary file via the usual c++/STL/iostream syntax.
i am copying the whole content into an dynamically allocated char array and this works fine so far.

but since i want to serve parts of the content as lines to another part of the program,
i think it would be better/easier to stick to streams because i don't want to hack around
with cstring functions and pointers.

my question now is, how can i store the read in memory. in a stringstream? or in a string?
which fits better? are there any advantages or disadvantages of one over the other?

thanks in advance!

Comment: ok, copying is easy after reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132358/how-to-read-file-content-into-istringstream

this (if it is true) also states that stringstreams internal buffer is a string (hence the name i guess). how can i reserve bytes for this buffer - i did not see any note on that in the ctor or anything about a reserve function ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to read from it as a stream, you might as well read directly from the file to the stringstream:

```
std::stringstream data;
data << input_file.rdbuf();
```

That reads the entire contents of 'input_file' into 'data'. You can read the data from there like you would any other stream.

Comment: thanks, already got that.
the question is now is it wise to store a stringstream as a kind of  memory/char buffer in my class? or should i use a string?

Comment: and what about std::stringbuf?

Comment: Lacking a specific reason to do otherwise, I'd just store the stringstream.