# Reading a file to a string in C++

Tags: c++, string, file

As somebody who is new to C++ and coming from a python background, I am trying to translate the code below to C++

```
f = open('transit_test.py')
s = f.read()
```

What is the shortest C++ idiom to do something like this?

Comment: you're just trying to showoff! :/

Comment: @JohnB: Or looking for sympathy?

Comment: I don't think reading a file is "showing off".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C++ STL way to do this is this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

wifstream f(L"transit_test.py");
wstring s(istreambuf_iterator<wchar_t>(f), (istreambuf_iterator<wchar_t>()) );
```

Comment: Yes, it will. Unfortunately, STL does not provide an automatic way of loading files in arbitrary encodings, so you either need to know the encoding of the file in advance and adjust the code accordingly or use a library to recognize the encoding and perform the appropriate conversion.

Comment: `R s(T(f), T());` is a function declaration.

Comment: @Abyx: `R s(T(f), (T()) );` isn't. ;)

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure I've posted this before, but it's sufficiently short it's probably not worth finding the previous answer:

```
std::ifstream in("transit_test.py");
std::stringstream buffer;

buffer << in.rdbuf();
```

Now `buffer.str()` is an `std::string` holding the contents of `transit_test.py`.

Comment: Does that not cause a redundant copy? How about this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132358/how-to-read-file-content-into-istringstream/138645#138645

Comment: @Martin: It does, but unless I encountered a real problem from it (which I haven't yet), I'd tend to wonder whether attempting to avoid it wasn't a premature optimization.

Answer (score -3):

You can do file read in C++ as like,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
    string line;
    ifstream in("transit_test.py"); //open file handler
    if(in.is_open()) //check if file open
    {
        while (!in.eof() ) //until the end of file
        {
            getline(in,line); //read each line
            // do something with the line
        }
        in.close(); //close file handler
    }
    else
    {
         cout << "Can not open file" << endl; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Along with being relatively long, this is buggy: it'll typically appear to read the last line twice (`while (!in.eof())` is pretty much a guaranteed bug).

Comment: Never put the test for eof in the while condition.