# how to pre-allocate memory for a std::string object?

Tags: c++, string

I need to copy a file into a string. I need someway to preallocate memory for that string object and a way to directly read the file content into that string's memory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read whole ASCII file into C++ std::string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602013/read-whole-ascii-file-into-c-stdstring) - My accepted answer to this question also explains how to pre-allocate all of the memory so that the string does not expand itself repeatedly during the read.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`std::string` [has a `.reserve` method](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/reserve) for pre-allocation.

```
std::string s;
s.reserve(1048576); // reserve 1 MB
read_file_into(s);
```

Comment: Would reserve string be helpful for `std::readline()` as well?

Answer (score 19):

This isn't so much an answer in itself, as a kind of a comment on/summary/comparison of a couple of other answers (as well as a quick demonstration of why I've recommended the style of code @Johannes - litb gives in his answer). Since @sbi posted an alternative that looked pretty good, and (especially) avoided the extra copy involved in reading into a stringstream, then using the `.str()` member to get a string, I decided to write up a quick comparison of the two:

[ Edit: I've added a third test case using @Tyler McHenry's `istreambuf_iterator`-based code, and added a line to print out the length of each string that was read to ensure that the optimizer didn't optimize away the reading because the result was never used.]

[ Edit2: And now, code from Martin York has been added as well...]

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    std::ostringstream os;
    std::ifstream file("equivs2.txt");

    clock_t start1 = clock();
    os << file.rdbuf();
    std::string s = os.str();
    clock_t stop1 = clock();

    std::cout << "\ns.length() = " << s.length();

    std::string s2;

    clock_t start2 = clock();
    file.seekg( 0, std::ios_base::end );
    const std::streampos pos = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);

    if( pos!=std::streampos(-1) )
        s2.reserve(static_cast<std::string::size_type>(pos));
    s2.assign(std::istream_iterator<char>(file), std::istream_iterator<char>());
    clock_t stop2 = clock();

    std::cout << "\ns2.length = " << s2.length();

    file.clear();

    std::string s3;

    clock_t start3 = clock();   
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);   
    s3.reserve(file.tellg());
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    s3.assign((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)),
            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    clock_t stop3 = clock();

    std::cout << "\ns3.length = " << s3.length();

    // New Test
    std::string s4;

    clock_t start4 = clock();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    s4.resize(file.tellg());
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    file.read(&s4[0], s4.length());
    clock_t stop4 = clock();

    std::cout << "\ns4.length = " << s3.length();

    std::cout << "\nTime using rdbuf: " << stop1 - start1;
    std::cout << "\nTime using istream_iterator: " << stop2- start2;
    std::cout << "\nTime using istreambuf_iterator: " << stop3 - start3;
    std::cout << "\nTime using read: " << stop4 - start4;
    return 0;
}
```

Now the impressive part -- the results. First with VC++ (in case somebody cares, Martin's code is fast enough I increased the file size to get a meaningful time for it):

> s.length() = 7669436
>   s2.length = 6390688
>   s3.length = 7669436
>   s4.length = 7669436
>   Time using rdbuf: 184
>   Time using istream_iterator: 1332
>   Time using istreambuf_iterator: 249
>   Time using read: 48

Then with gcc (cygwin):

> s.length() = 8278035
>   s2.length = 6390689
>   s3.length = 8278035
>   s4.length = 8278035
>   Time using rdbuf: 62
>   Time using istream_iterator: 2199
>   Time using istreambuf_iterator: 156
>   Time using read: 16

[ end of edit -- the conclusions remain, though the winner has changed -- Martin's code is *clearly* the fastest. ]

The results are quite consistent with respect to which is fastest and slowest. The only inconsistency is with how *much* faster or slower one is than another. Though the placements are the same, the speed differences are *much* larger with gcc than with VC++.

Comment: Sort of what i thought initially: It's much easier to optimize the char-by-char read of op<< into a block read (or inline appropriate parts) than the char-by-char read of istream_iterator (though such code has to use `istreambuf_iterator` to avoid skipping whitespace for each character read - maybe that will speed things up since it's happening on a lower level?), which goes over multiple steps with op++, op* etc. But i didn't expect it would make *that* much of a difference. Thanks for timing it!

Comment: Could you write what compilation flags were used for test cases?

Answer (score 6):

This should be all you need:

```
ostringstream os;
ifstream file("name.txt");
os << file.rdbuf();

string s = os.str();
```

This reads characters from `file` and inserts them into the stringstream. Afterwards it gets the string created behind the scenes. Notice that i fell into the following trap: Using the extraction operator will skip initial whitespace. You have to use the insertion operator like above, or use the `noskipws` manipulator:

```
// Beware, skips initial whitespace!
file >> os.rdbuf();

// This does not skip it
file >> noskipws >> os.rdbuf();
```

These functions are described as reading the stream character by character though (not sure what optimizations are possible here, though), i haven't timed these to determine their speed.

Comment: this does copy twice, once to `ostringstream` buffer  and second time to `s`

Comment: @Johannes, I was assuming the string memory to be contagious buffer, but after reading @GMan 's answer I realized that there is no way around the copying.

Comment: @Gollum: As I pointed out in an answer yesterday, I've used code like the above a lot without a problem, but if the extra copy causes a real problem, consider a previous answer Martin York pointed out yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132358/how-to-read-file-content-into-istringstream/138645#138645.

Comment: @Jerry, checked that answer, but that uses `vector<char>` which again needs to be copied in to a `string`

Comment: @Gollum: yes, but given the (soon to be official) requirement that `string` use a contiguous buffer, you could resize the string and use its buffer instead of the `vector<char>`.

Comment: @Gollum: Do you really need a string, even? In any case, I would use this answer. If performance becomes a problem, then you can either: 1) replace your string usage with a vector, removing a copy or 2) Make an implementation assumption (a rather safe one) and read directly into the string, removing a copy. 3) [Copy char-by-char into the string from the file.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303527/how-to-pre-allocate-memory-for-a-stdstring-object/3303764#3303764)

Comment: @Gollum: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303527/how-to-pre-allocate-memory-for-a-stdstring-object/3303764#3303764) for how to do away with the copy.

Comment: @Jerry: Interesting, Martin's answer is similar to [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303527/how-to-pre-allocate-memory-for-a-stdstring-object/3303764#3303764). However, he read the data as binary, (not translating platform-specific newlines), while I read textually. Also I get away without the extra copy.

Comment: @Gollum my comment about block-reads was a bit too ambitious i guess :) Looks like even op<< has to read it char-by-char :(

Comment: @Johannes, although `ifstream.read (&my_str[0], length)` is a block read with assumption of string objects being in the contiguous block of memory, is it too dangerous an assuption? or pragmatic?

Comment: @Gollum: I'm sure in practice that's Ok. (There haven't been any non-contiguous string implementations around.) But the difference is that it performs binary read.

Comment: @sbi, right, that might be a good reason to not use it on formatted strings.

Comment: @Gollum herb sutter teaches his fellows that `&my_str[0]` points to a contiguous area of memory. He says at http://herbsutter.com/2008/04/07/cringe-not-vectors-are-guaranteed-to-be-contiguous/ : "However, current ISO C++ does require &str[0] to cough up a pointer to contiguous string data (but not necessarily null-terminated!), so there wasn’t much leeway for implementers to have non-contiguous strings, anyway.", although string's wording in current Std is broken in exactly that regard (refers to a non-const `data()` - but that doesn't exist!) - so it can't be relied on.

Comment: Like @sbi says i think in practice that's fine :)

Answer (score 5):

Just for fun, here's another way to do this:

```
// Beware, brain-compiled code ahead!

std::ifstream ifs( /* ... */ );
if( !ifs.good() ) return; // whatever

std::string str;

ifs.seekg( 0, std::ios_base::end );
const std::streampos pos = ifs.tellg();
ifs.seekg( 0, std::ios_base::beg );
if( pos!=std::streampos(-1) ) // can get stream size? 
  str.reserve(static_cast<std::string::size_type>(pos));

str.assign( std::istream_iterator<char>(ifs)
          , std::istream_iterator<char>() );
```

I hope I didn't blow it too badly.

Comment: +1, was waiting for someone to elaborate stream iterator based code :)

Comment: +1, for flexible `Brain-Compiler` is okay with missing `}` ;)

Comment: @Gollum: I freely admit I copied those `seekg()` lines straight out of some code of mine (which fills a string with a file's content) and overlooked the `{`. I fixed it, but that's what that disclaimer is for, anyway.

Answer (score 5):

`std::string::resize()` actually allocates the required space.

`std::string::reserve()` may not (it's a request).

Comment: Nope, I have found that resize for std::string is slow 2.9 secs for a 4GB string , whereas reserve lasts about 0.7 secs. Better use reserve for std::string. Use resize only for std::vectors where there is much faster.

Answer (score 1):

[std::string::reserve()](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/basic_string.html)

[std::getline()](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/string/getline)

Comment: That is one horrific link to a blocked site.  https://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/reserve/ or https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/reserve are preferred.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are asking how to do a CString::GetBuffer, ReleaseBuffer type operation with std::string.

I don't know of any way to do this directly, an easy way would be to just create a raw C style buffer, read into the buffer, then copy the buffer to a std::string using assign or whatever. Of course you would have to worry about buffer overrun issues etc., also I would use a std::autoptr to manage the raw buffer pointer, to enusre deallocation on exception etc. This is a bit simpler than using stringstream etc. I can provide an example if needed.

Devin Ellingson

Comment: `auto_ptr` doesn't handle array types correctly. Just use `std::vector`. (Also, signing posts is frowned upon; your name is under everything you do.)

Comment: Thanks GMan, I forgot about that problem, auto_ptr always calls delete instead of delete [], which is whatwould be needed in this case. 

You could just create a simple array_auto_ptr class or as you say use std::vector.