# What's the most efficient way of reading an ifstream into an string?

Tags: c++, std

noob question! How can i read 'a whole ifstream' into a stdlib 'string'? The current way i'm using for all my projects right now wastes much time i think:

```
string code;
ifstream input("~/myfile");
char c1=input.get();
while (c1!=EOF)
{
    code+=c1;
    len++;
    c1=input.get();
}
```

BTW i prefer to do line and whitespace management myself.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303527/how-to-pre-allocate-memory-for-a-stdstring-object/3304059#3304059

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
string load_file(const string& filename)
{
    ifstream infile(filename.c_str(), ios::binary);
    istreambuf_iterator<char> begin(infile), end;
    return string(begin, end);
}
```

Comment: This using iterators is more standard i think. I'll benchmark to see what way is faster though.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   std::string s;

   std::getline(std::cin, s, '\0');
   std::cout << s;
}
```

~