# How can I find out how many bytes are available from a std::istream?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, istream

If I wanted to `read()` the content of a `std::istream` in to a buffer, I would have to find out how much data was available first to know how big to make the buffer. And to get the number of available bytes from an istream, I am currently doing something like this:

```
std::streamsize available( std::istream &is )
{
    std::streampos pos = is.tellg();
    is.seekg( 0, std::ios::end );
    std::streamsize len = is.tellg() - pos;
    is.seekg( pos );
    return len;
}
```

And similarly, since std::istream::eof() isn't a very useful fundtion AFAICT, to find out if the `istream`'s get pointer is at the end of the stream, I'm doing this:

```
bool at_eof( std::istream &is )
{
    return available( is ) == 0;
}
```

My question:

Is there a better way of getting the number of available bytes from an `istream`? If not in the standard library, in boost, perhaps?

Comment: *I would have to find out how much data was available first to know how big to make the buffer* - not true. See [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420317/c-reading-and-writing-binary-file/5420568#5420568) (second part).

Comment: Wow, interesting answer. I think this will work. Thankyou!

Comment: @edam: Why do you need to know the buffer size in advance, can you not read as much as the buffer you have?

Comment: @Als: I need to allocate a buffer, fill it with data from the `istream` and pass it to a library with a C-style API. So, ultimately, I need a pointer to the data and the length of the data.

Comment: @edam: If you need to read all the data in one go, then @Space_C0wb0y, answer in the link does just that, else you can always read data by the size you allocate and then use it further on, Anyhow the solution suggested seems better.

Comment: @Als: yes, @Space_C0wb0y, you should post your suggestion as an answer!

Comment: You might want to look through my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303527/how-to-pre-allocate-memory-for-a-stdstring-object/3304059#3304059) to a previous question. The bottom line is that while  @Space_C0wb0y's answer seems like it should be a good one, there are alternatives that are generally better -- almost regardless of what tradeoff between speed and elegance you prefer (in particular, the `sstream << stream.rdbuf();` elegant *and* quite fast, though not the fastest).

Answer (score 4):

For `std::cin` you don't need to worry about buffering because it is buffered already --- and you can't predict how many keys the user strokes.

For opened binary `std::ifstream`, which are also buffered, you can call the `seekg(0, std::ios:end)` and `tellg()` methods to determine, how many bytes are there.

You can also call the `gcount()` method after reading:

```
char buffer[SIZE];

while (in.read(buffer,SIZE))
{
  std::streamsize num = in.gcount();
  // call your API with num bytes in buffer 
}
```

For text input reading via `std::getline(inputstream, a_string)` and analyzing that string afterwards can be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Posting this as an answer, as it seems to be what the OP wants.

*I would have to find out how much data was available first to know how big to make the buffer* - not true. See [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420317/reading-and-writing-binary-file/5420568#5420568) (second part).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work quite right... Using `istream_iterator< char >` skips spaces on the `istream`, even when you use it with `copy()`. So the `vector< char>` buffer that you end up with has all spaces removed!