# Performance of string streams versus file I/O streams in C++

Tags: c++, file, io

I have to read in a huge text file (>200,000 words) and process each word. I read in the entire file into a string and then attach a string stream to it to process easily each word. The approach is I directly input each word from file using `<<` and process it but comparing both the approaches does not give me any advantage in terms of execution time. Isn't it faster to operate on a string in memory than from a file which needs a system call every time I need a word? Please suggest some performance enhancing methods.

Comment: stream does some buffering internally. Fiddle with the buffer size to find optimal fit.

Comment: See @Martin York's answer here for a 'stringstream from file' that minimizes copying - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132358/how-to-read-file-content-into-istringstream

Comment: @Martin: but he should probably also read the comments and (if I might be so bold) my answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3303527/179910. To make a long story short, the method I've given below, seems to be faster pretty consistently. I think most of the problem is that seeking to the end of the file takes more time than the internal copying it avoids.

Comment: Post some code. Are you sure it is the IO that is the bottleneck here? Have you profiled it?

Comment: Why is this tagged `c`? Anyway ... try opening the file in "binary" mode (`fopen("hugefile", "rb")` in C) to make the runtime library **NOT** do end-of-line, and possibly other, translations.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: You can be as bold as you like. I just tried my method and it was twice as quick as your best method (though I was only using a 6M file to test with). I have added a couple of lines to your code. If you want to-run your tests and update the results with the last test.

Comment: @Martin: Yup -- it is quick. I did have to do a bit of work on the code to get it to compile (was missing a definition of `s4`), but I should have some updated results there soon. Nice work!

Answer (score 5):

For performance and minimal copying, this is hard to beat (as long as you have enough memory!):

```
void mapped(const char* fname)
{
  using namespace boost::interprocess;

  //Create a file mapping
  file_mapping m_file(fname, read_only);

  //Map the whole file with read permissions
  mapped_region region(m_file, read_only);

  //Get the address of the mapped region
  void * addr       = region.get_address();
  std::size_t size  = region.get_size();

  // Now you have the underlying data...
  char *data = static_cast<char*>(addr);

  std::stringstream localStream;
  localStream.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(data, size);

  // now you can do your stuff with the stream
  // alternatively
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to put the data into a stringstream anyway, it's probably a bit faster and easier to copy directly from the input stream to the string stream:

```
std::ifstream infile("yourfile.txt");
std::stringstream buffer;

buffer << infile.rdbuf();
```

The `ifstream` will use a buffer, however, so while that's probably faster than reading into a string, then creating a stringstream, it may not be any faster than working directly from the input stream.

Comment: If there is other I/O going on in parallel with this processing, then one-shot load of data will be preferable as disk head does not have the same opportunity to move between buffer refreshes.

Comment: I think this combined with Martin's answer to previous q will perform the best.  I gave you +1 for best local info

Comment: @ruslik - where is there mention of async I/O?  How is memory-mapped file different from loading entire file contents using STL, apart from complexity and non-portability of the former?

Comment: @Steve: memory mapping *can* be considerably different if you don't have (close to) enough physical memory to hold the entire file. In such a case, loading the entire file basically ends up copying the data into memory, then copying it back out to the paging file, then reading it back in from the paging file when used. Memory mapping avoids all but the last of those. On Windows it typically helps only a little, but on Linux it can be *extremely* effective.

Comment: @Jerry - right, but 200K words is the problem as stated.  1-2MB tops?

Comment: @Steve: Quite true -- for this particular problem, it's unlikely to make a real difference. For the same program processing a large input, however, the difference could become much more significant.

Answer (score 1):

There is caching involved, so it does not necessarily do a system call each time you extract. Having said that, you may get marginally better performance at parse time by parsing a single contiguous buffer. On the other hand, you are serializing the workload (read entire file, then parse), which can potentially be parallelized (read and parse in parallel).

Answer (score 1):

The string will get reallocated and copied an awful lot of times to accommodate 200,000 words. That's probably what is taking the time.

You should use a rope if you want to create a huge string by appending.