# Loading a file into a vector<unsigned char>

Tags: c++, iostream

This question is very similar to [Loading a file into a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241871/loading-a-file-into-a-vectorchar); however, in this case, I want to load it into a vector of unsigned chars.

Using the code from the other question, what is the best way to load an unsigned char vector?

```
std::vector<char> vec;  // Would like this to be std::vector<unsigned char> vec;
std::ifstream file;
file.exceptions(
    std::ifstream::badbit
  | std::ifstream::failbit
  | std::ifstream::eofbit);
file.open("test.txt");
file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
std::streampos length(file.tellg());
if (length) {
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    vec.resize(static_cast<std::size_t>(length));
    file.read(&vec.front(), static_cast<std::size_t>(length));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `std::vector<char> vec;` to `std::vector<unsigned char> vec;`

Comment: I get the following compilation error when doing that:
invalid conversion from 'unsigned char*' to 'std::basic_istream<char>::char_type* {aka char*}'

Comment: @MachoMatt Add a cast to the first argument of your call to the read function: `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&vec.front())`

Comment: Accepted with @benjamin-lindley's comment.  Both the accepted answer and the comment are needed.