# How do I read character by character from a text file and put it in a character array?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read character by character from a text file until EOF, put them into a character array, so that I can manipulate it after. Compiled with g++ without errors, and when run, I'm prompted for the input file but then it just hangs.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    string filename;
    ifstream infile;

    char *cp, c[1024];
    memset (c, 0, sizeof(c));
    cp = c;

    cout << "Enter file name: " << endl;
    cin >> filename;

    //open file
    infile.open( filename.c_str() );

    //if file can't open
    if(!infile) {
        cerr << "Error: file could not be opened" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    while (!infile.eof()); {
        infile.get(c, sizeof(infile));
       // get character from file and store in array c[]
    }
}//end main
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/7241871/485561

Comment: You shouldn't read char by char. This is not the 1980s anymore...

Comment: I should've mentioned that it's for my assignment, but that's good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the `istream::read()` method rather than `get()`.  This will help resolve any buffer overruns:

```
unsigned int chars_read = 0;
//...
// Read in the file.
if (!infile.read(c, sizeof(c))
{
    // Handle the read error here.
    // Also check for EOF here too.
}

// Obtain the number of characters actually read.
chars_read = infile.gcount();
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you **don't** want to test for `eof()`! Somehow I start to feel like Don Quixote having found my windmills. However, I do know that you need to check that the input was successful **after** trying to read it because before attempting to read the stream can't know whether it will be successful.

You program actually doesn't hang! It just waits for you to enter `sizeof(infile)` characters or end the input (e.g., using Ctrl-D on UNIXes and Ctrl-Z on Windows). Of course, this may look remarkable like a hanging program. You can verify that this is, indeed, the problem by using a smaller size, e.g., `4`. Of course, `sizeof(infile)` is nearly as good as a small random number: It is the size of an object of type `std::ifstream` and who can tell what that is? You probably meant to use `sizeof(c)` to make sure that the call to `get(c, n)` won't write more character than can fit into `c`.

Comment: The OP also needs to check the amount of characters read vs. the capacity of the array.  Otherwise a buffer overflow will occur.

Comment: Thanks everyone, changing sizeof(c) and doing an infile.gcount() has helped. I did notice that when my file is being read, it only reads up until the next return line (hence only one line is read)?

Comment: I had used infile.get() and infile.read(), but infile.read() ignores new lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int cont = 0;
while(infile.good()) {
  c[cont++] = infile.get();
}
```

Comment: Possible buffer overflow with your solution.  If the file size is greater than 1024, this starts writing beyond the array.

Comment: Yes, but don't blame me, he's the one who put the limit :D