# Reading binary file into vector<char> reading less than full file

Tags: c++, vector, ifstream

I have binary files whose contents I'm trying to read into a vector. All the files are the same size, yet using my code below, the final vector size is always a little bit smaller than the file size, and it's different from file to file (but same for each file). I'm confused at what is going on here...

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::string filename(argv[1]);

  // Get file size
  std::ifstream ifs(filename, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
  int size = (int)ifs.tellg();
  std::cout << "Detected " << filename << " size: " << size << std::endl; // seems correct!

  // Load file
  ifs.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
  std::istream_iterator<char unsigned> start(ifs), end;
  std::vector<char unsigned> v;
  v.reserve(size);
  v.assign(start, end);

  std::cout << "Loaded data from " << filename << ", with " << v.size() << " elements" << std::endl; 
}
```

Trying this on a file, I get this:

```
Detected foo_binary.bin size: 2113753
Loaded data from foo_binary.bin, with 2099650 elements
```

The 2113753 number is the correct size of the file in bytes.

Trying this on another file of the same size, the vector size will end up having 2100700 elements. A bit more, but again not the whole file.

What's going on here?

Comment: Do you get the same thing using one of [thses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241871/loading-a-file-into-a-vectorchar) methods?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are multiple stream iterators. The class template `std::istream_iterator<T>` is for *formatted* input, i.e., it is going go skip leading whitespace before trying to read an object of type `T`.

From the looks of it you want `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>` which is used to iterate over the characters in a file, not doing any skipping.