# How do I reverse the a array of chars and store them in a new file?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, reverse

I've been trying to solve this problem without using pointers, only with the basics (I'm a student) but I can't fine the solution.

```
void ReverseFile() {

FILE *originalM, *fin;

fopen_s(&originalM, "original.txt", "r");
fopen_s(&fin, "inverted.txt", "w");

char arr[100];

for (int i = 0; i < 100 && !feof(originalM); i++)
{
    fscanf_s(originalM, "%c ", &arr[i]);
    cout << arr[i] ;
}
cout << endl;
fclose(originalM);

for (int i = 0, k = 100; i < 100; i++, k--) 
{
    arr[k] = arr[i];
    cout << arr[k];
}
fclose(fin);}
```

So far I have this function and one file of text (originalM.txt) which contains chars (with a space in between):

> e e a a e e a a e e a a

In the first loop I get each char of the file and save it in the array. The problem comes in the second loop, where I want to reverse them. How can I solve this? I was trying to create a new array and store the chars but that doesn't work. Also I was trying to print it into the new file with this:

```
fprintf(fin, "%c ", &arr[k]);
```

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Are you happy to use std::reverse?

Comment: You've tagged both C and C++ . They are different languages.

Comment: you write in the same array. and @YuriyIvaskevych this can not be C because C has no `cout`

Comment: @UKMonkey Umm interesting, sure.

Comment: Have you heard of `std::vector`?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Fixed, sorry.

Comment: @KamiKaze I know that, but pointing out to the OP that they are different.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes but i can't use it in this function... (It's a requirement of the teacher)

Comment: Start with finding a better teacher. Particularly one that doesn't think this sort of crippling requirement is "teaching you the real C++".

Comment: @StoryTeller I'd wager on this level it is not about teaching you real C++ but just trying to get them wrap their head around programming. Which is more than enough to my mind as general programming education should not go into the depths of language specifics

Comment: @StoryTeller Hahaha okey, anyway I will be grateful if you help me with the vector.

Comment: @KamiKaze - I consider the attitude that forces pupils to use the `cstring` library instead of `std::string` as the exact opposite. They don't get to just "wrap their head around programming" because they constantly need to chase the very intricate details you claim they are sheltered from. It's much more intuitive to do `std::string str = "Hello World";` than wonder why your program segfaults after you defined `char *str = "Hello  World!";`

Comment: @StoryTeller well I exactly disagree with that way, because (given it was explained beforehand) the more basic handling of arrays/pointers gives more insight to the basics. After they grasped the basic concepts you can move on to use such things from `std`. And `std::string` wouldn't help you if would want to rearrange an integer array. So a small modification will hand you the same problem again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ and by using vector and stream iterators, you can do this (generalized for arbitrary number of characters):

```
void reverseFile(const string& in, const string& out)
{
    ifstream input(in);
    ofstream output(out);
    istream_iterator<char> inStart(input), inEnd;
    // load from the input file
    vector<char> data(inStart, inEnd);
    // copy back to the output file in reversed order
    copy(data.rbegin(), data.rend(), ostream_iterator<char>(output));
}
```

---

If you'd like to retain the spaces in between the characters, the `ostream_iterator` also supports a `delimiter` parameter, so to retain spaces, you can simply add it to the line:

```
copy(data.rbegin(), data.rend(), ostream_iterator<char>(output, " "));
```

Comment: Now this is a thing of beauty :)

Comment: Okey it takes me a bit to understand but i get it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) to reverse `arr` in-place. Unless you're always sure that all `100` values of `arr` will contain meaningful values, you need to keep track of how many values you read.

Everything becomes trivial when you use idiomatic C++:

- [`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) and [`std::ofstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream) can be used for file input/output.
- [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) can be used as a generic resizable array.
- [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) can be used to load the entire original file into memory.

```
void ReverseFile() 
{
    std::ifstream ifs{"original.txt"};

    // Read from `ifs` into a `arr` vector.
    // (From "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241871").
    std::ostringstream oss;
    ss << file.rdbuf();
    const auto& s = ss.str();
    std::vector<char> arr(s.begin(), s.end());

    // Reverse `arr` in place:
    std::reverse(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));

    // Save `arr` to file.
    std::ofstream ofs{"inverted.txt"};
    for(auto x : arr) ofs << x;
    ofs.flush(); 
    ofs.close();
}
```

Comment: There is another way instead of using for(auto)? I can do it just with a normal for right?

Comment: @Kamelo10: yes, but why would you want to?

Comment: Hmm... why the assumption the entire 100 characters are read?

Comment: @StoryTeller: the incorrect loop that was meant to reverse the values in OP's code was looping over all 100 elements, that's why I made the assumption.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo - The OP was wrong to make it. And answers would be wrong to maintain it. It's not just about showcasing shiny C++ features, after all.

Comment: @StoryTeller: no need to be condescending. As I incorrectly assumed that the OP was interested in all `100` elements you should not assume that I simply want to *"showcase shiny C++ features"*. Also, considering `std::reverse` and range-`for` *"shiny C++ features"* instead of fundamental building block for programs is a counter-productive attitude.

Comment: I have nothing against the fundamental building blocks of software. A range based for is a nicety that is irrelevant to the correctness of the OP's code. Since your answer started with that, and originally completely overlooked the OP's bug, it's not a leap of me to say you missed the point by setting your sights on getting it to look like C++11 instead of just correct C++ in general.

Comment: @StoryTeller: yes, I didn't think about the possibility of `arr` being only partially filled with meaningful values as I was misled by OP's second for loop's ranges. That was my mistake. Blaming that on my suggestion of using Modern C++ features is completely ridiculous though.

Comment: `for`-range loops are the default choice for me and should be the general default choice. I would have to use more of my brain processing power to suggest a non-range-`for` loop as there needs to be a good reason for that. Regardless, the OP didn't keep track of the number of read characters anywhere either, so I would have had to introduce a counter independently from my iteration construct choice. Therefore, my *"desire of showing shiny C++11 features*" has nothing to do with my wrong assumption *(which, obviously, was a mistake on my part)*.

Comment: I never postulated anything about your desires. I pointed out what I considered an error in the answers priorities. Seeing as it was all edited away, arguing about it further is moot.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, suppose you have read some string into array `char arr[100];`. Now to reverse it you can use something like this:

```
size_t length = strlen(arr);
for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; ++i)
{
    char swapChar = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[length-i-1];
    arr[length-i-1] = swapChar;
}
```

Instead of 3 statements inside of that `for` loop you can use [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap):

`std::swap(arr[i], arr[length-i-1]);`

Another way is to use `std::reverse` as already answered by @VittorioRomeo.

**Edit 1:** Thanks to @StoryTeller for pointing out that your array should be NULL-terminated in order for `strlen` to work. So after you've read data (say `l` characters) do `arr[l] = '\0';`

Comment: Using `strlen` to get the length of a C-style array is a bad idea. You can statically get the size at compile-time using `sizeof` *(a better idea would be [using a template function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18078435/598696))*. The rest of the answer is interesting for educational purpose but I would strongly recommend using `std::reverse` instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Calling `strlen` is undefined behavior since the array is filed with indeterminate values, and the OP does not NUL terminate it.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Also `std::string` or `std::vector<char>` could be used to store data. So back to `sizeof` - what if we read less characters that 100 (or whatever allocated size)?

Comment: @StoryTeller yes, thanks for pointing that out, fixed and edited.

Answer (score 0):

You're using this code to reverse:

```
for (int i = 0, k = 100; i < 100; i++, k--) 
{
    arr[k] = arr[i];
    cout << arr[k];
}
```

Think of it. In first 50 iterations you *rewrite* first half of array with the data of a second part, mirrored, in second 50 iterations you *rewrite* the second part with what you have copied into the first. What you need here is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) 
{
    char tmp; //you can use std::swap instead.
    tmp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[100-i];
    arr[100-i] = tmp;
}
```

Solutions like std::reverse are better, of course.

Comment: Okey I understand.

Comment: But... did you profile it? For only 100 characters the time difference should not be noticeable, but for greater sizes, your algorithm could break *locality* and make the hardware cache less useful, resulting in less efficient code. Always carefully profile all low level optimization attempts!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just save it in reverse order?

```
void ReverseFile() {
    FILE *originalM, *fin;
    fopen_s(&originalM, "original.txt", "r");
    fopen_s(&fin, "inverted.txt", "w");

    char arr[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100 && !feof(originalM); i++)
    {
        fscanf_s(originalM, "%c ", &arr[i]);
        cout << arr[i] ;
    }
    cout << endl;
    fclose(originalM);

    for (int k = i - 1, k >= 0; k--) 
    {
        cout << arr[k];
    }
    fclose(fin);
}
```