# Pointers, passing arguments to main, and segfaults

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, command-line-arguments

The three things mentioned in the title are somewhat new to me.  I am familiar with all of them conceptually but this is the first time I have tried to write my own program from scratch in C++ and it involves all three of these things.  Here is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
FILE *dataFile;
char string [180];
dataFile = fopen(argv[1],"r");
fgets(string,180,dataFile);
fclose(dataFile);
}
```

It compiles fine, but when I execute using a simple input text file I get a segmentation fault.  I have searched multiple tutorials and I can't figure out why.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What arguments are you passing through the command line (`argv`)?

Comment: @Aesthete There is just one filename.  testRead.txt it is called.

Comment: Have you checked if you have enough permissions to read the file?

Comment: If I understand how permissions work (which I may not) then I think I do.  It is in my home directory anyway.  (I'm on OSX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you should be checking here. It still may not do what you expect, but it will avoid the errors you're getting.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  if(argc > 1) // FIRST make sure that there are arguments, otherwise no point continuing.
  { 
    FILE* dataFile = NULL; // Initialize your pointers as NULL.
    const unsigned int SIZE = 180; // Try and use constants for buffers. 
                                      Use this variable again later, and if 
                                      something changes - it's only in one place.
    char string[SIZE];
    dataFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(dataFile) // Make sure your file opened for reading.
    {
      fgets(string, SIZE, dataFile); // Process your file.
      fclose(dataFile); // Close your file.
    }
  }
}
```

Remember that after this, `string` may still be NULL. See ['fgets' for more information.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. That is very helpful to me since I am trying to develop better coding practices. I have another question actually after reading through your post. I am now trying to read in each line of a multiline file until the end of file is reached and am having a lot of trouble.  Could I use a loop and check if string is NULL in order to signal the end of the file? (Also, would it be better if I post this as a new question?)

Comment: Have look at `std::stringstream`, `std::getline' and their related classes. This should get you started - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132358/how-to-read-file-content-into-istringstream

Answer (score 2):

There are two likely causes of a segmentation fault in your code:

- `argv[1]` does not exist, in which case attempting to access it may result in a segfault. Check `if (argc > 1)` to avoid this problem.
- `fopen` does not successfully open the file, in which case attempting to read from the file (`fgets`) or `fclose` it will cause a segmentation fault. Immediately after a call to fopen, you should check that the return value is not `NULL`, e.g. `if (dataFile == NULL)`.

Comment: Thank you, I checked those things and in fact the return value was NULL.  I copy-pasted the data from the file into a different file and resaved it just on a whim not expecting it to work but it did.  I have no idea what was wrong with the original file since it too was just a .txt file.  I'm still somewhat confused but glad it works now.