# get unread section of istringstream

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a test where I get characters out of an `std::istringstream`.  I would like to get the section of the `std::istringstream` that was not read during the test.  The `std::istringstream::str()` function returns the entire string, not just the unread section.

How do I get just this section of the string?

Comment: `std::getline(mystringstream, rest_of_string)`

Comment: @MooingDuck Wouldn't this just read until.. the end of the line? (And not until the `eof` of the `istringstream`.)

Comment: oops.  `std::getline(mystringstream, rest_of_string, 0);` will read until it finds a NULL or EOF, which is closer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you don't manually set the input position indicator before this line:

```
std::string unread = stream.eof()  ?  "" : stream.str().substr( stream.tellg() );
```

Comment: Will that work for all implementations of std::istringstream?

Comment: @Graznarak Yes, there nothing implementation specific here.

Comment: @DyP I don't quite understand. I'm not using `rdbuf()->str()` which i know will return the entire string.

Comment: @DyP Right, I was thinking about something else ;)

Comment: @0x499602D2 This doesn't work with a std::istringstream with an empty string.  At least it doesn't in VS2012.

Comment: @Graznarak Do you mean when the stream is declared as `stringstream stream("")`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Yes.  Also, same failure when the entire input has been consumed.

Comment: You'll probably need a check for `-1`, as `tellg` returns that in some (these) cases.

Comment: @Graznarak Try `std::string unread = stream.tellg() == -1 ? stream.str().substr( stream.tellg() ) : "";`

Comment: @0x499602D2 It appears to only happen when the entire input stream has been consumed and has returned eof().  I get a std::out_of_range exception from it, which matches expected exceptions from std::string::substr().

Comment: @Graznarak See if using `stream.eof()` as the ternary condition instead of `.tellg() == -1` works.

Comment: @Graznarak Please try my update. I made a mistake with my previous code.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this I think is to push the read buffer of the `istringstream` to a string stream:

```
void test(std::istringstream& iss)
{
  /* Test code */
}

int main()
{
   std::istringstream iss;
   std::stringstream not_readed_buffer;
  std::string not_readed;

   test( iss );

   if( iss )
   {
       not_readed_buffer << iss.rdbuf();
       not_readed = not_readed_buffer.str();    
   }
}
```

Check [this answer for a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/132394/1609356)